# Event after BackgroundWorker thread is aborted

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Perhaps I am over thinking this but I have a number of threads doing a rather lengthy  process and I want to be able to cleanly abort them if necessary.   This is primarily because I don't want to start new threads until the old ones are finished.  Is there a way to tell via Event or other method that a thread is fully aborted?  Or should I not worry about this?   Currently I have code in my abort method as follows:

```
    private void AbortProcessing()
    {
        if (!Processing) return;
        StopFlag = true;
        for (int x = 0; x < MaxThreads; x++)
        {
            try
            {
                BW[x].CancelAsync();
            }
            catch { }
            //Processing = false;
        }
        bool aborted = false;
        while (!aborted)
        {
            aborted = true;
            for (int x = 0; x < MaxThreads; x++)
            {
                if (BW[x].IsBusy) aborted = false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        }
    }
```

The IsBusy is always true, forever, after signalling abort so this doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did any of the BackgroudWorker working methods check if the should cancel the operation?

Comment: `CancelAsync()` simply signals that the Thread should be aborted.  Are you actually checking that flag in the background thread and exiting it?  This doesn't happen automatically...

Comment: This is a classic case of *deadlock*, one of the universal threading bugs.  A BGW can only complete after its RunWorkerCompleted event runs.  It cannot run, you are hanging the UI thread by looping and sleeping.  Providing you with a better solution is not possible when you don't describe why you think you need to loop.

Comment: Idle_Mind, I am checking and quitting the processing of CancellationPending is true.  I guess I thought that some other event or flag would trigger when the thread finishes under this condition.  It doesn't seem that the RunWorkerCompleted event fires but I could be wrong.  I wonder if I can just set IsBusy to false at this point.  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

try this:Simple Sample for this

```
       Thread o;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart starter = ThreaadFunction;
        starter += () => {

            //this is this event you want to do any thing after a threaad finished the job


        };
        o = new Thread(starter) {IsBackground =true };
        o.Start();
    }

    public void ThreaadFunction()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // what you do in thread
    }
}
```